# How to get map-scale using bing-api?

Tags: c#, javascript, bing-api, bing-maps

As shown in the bing-map bellow, there are two numbers in the bottom (eg: here 500 miles and 1000 km). What do they mean? I am using bing-api. **How to get these two numbers using bing-API**?

[image]

Comment: Did you get the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

**API reference:**

If you are using the AJAX v7 control, then you have the `getMetersPerPixel` method on the Map class that will return the number of meter for one pixel.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx

If you want to use it with a specific dimension of a element on the screen, then you need to multiply by the size (in pixel) of your elements.

**Example:**

Here is a really cool example from my fellow Alastair:

http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-a-custom-bing-maps-scale-bar-a-k-a-yes-but-how-many-space-needles-is-that/